# BaseAdapter Listview Filtering Android

Tags: android, listview

In my `Listview`, I am having text and image and they are stored in `ArrayList`.

I am using `BaseAdapter` to display the list.

I want to use `filter` on the list based on text typed in `EditText`, but is not working.

My code is : adv is EditText

```
  adv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                viewadapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

And my `BaseAdapter` implements `Filterable` so `getFilter` method in that is:

```
@Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if (mFilter == null) {
                    mFilter = new ArrayFilter();
                }
                return mFilter;
        }
```

and my `ArrayFilter` is:

```
 private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (mNames == null) {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    mNames = new ArrayList<String>(mObjects);
                }
            }

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(mNames);
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                }
            } else {
                String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                final ArrayList<String> values = mNames;
                final int count = values.size();

                final ArrayList<String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>(count);

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    final String value = values.get(i);
                    final String valueText = value.toString().toLowerCase();

                    // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                    if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                        newValues.add(value);
                    } else {
                        final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
                        final int wordCount = words.length;

                        for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                            if (words[k].startsWith(prefixString)) {
                                newValues.add(value);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            mObjects = (List<String>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                viewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                viewadapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }

    }
}
```

in that `mNames` is the `ArrayList` with which I want to filter the `ListView`.

and also enabled `setTextFilterEnabled(true).`, but filtering is not working.

Is this correct approach? what's wrong in it? if not, how to do that?

Comment: Did you fix this problem? Could you give us a feedback?

Comment: No I didnt get solved, thats y i kept it open !! If you got so please post here Thanx

Comment: how you saved text and image in ArrayList<String>???

Comment: **i hope this example could help you**

[example of how to use getfilter with baseadapter][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456525/how-to-filter-listview-using-getfilter-in-baseadapter/14359161#14359161

Answer (score 0):

this the API demo example

```
public class SearchViewFilterMode extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SearchViewFilterMode";

    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    private final String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.searchview_filter);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mStrings));
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
        mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.cheese_hunt_hint));
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```