# Why is getFilter() for ListView Search Throwing NullPointer?

Tags: android, listview, search, filter, nullpointerexception

I am a noob to android development and I am having trouble implementing searchable ListView.  I started by using this [android hive tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/) and I made my custom adapter Filterable and overrided the getFilter method as explained by the SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456525/how-to-filter-listview-using-getfilter-in-baseadapter).   However, when i run my application as is it crashes due to a null pointer exception. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Main Activity

```
public class StoresActivity extends SherlockActivity /*implements OnQueryTextListener*/ {
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> storeList;
 ListView list;
 LazyAdapter adapter;
 EditText inputSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stores);

    storeList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Oleref", 2);      

    String employee = preferences.getString("employee", null);
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.bhfd.com"+ employee});
    try {
        storeList = task.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, storeList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setItemsCanFocus(true);


    //Search Bar for Listview
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch); //<--search bar 
    if(adapter!=null){
    }
     inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                StoresActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  //<--NullPointer here


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });     

}
```

Custom Adapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public String sn;
StoresActivity storesActivity;
HashMap<String, String> stores;
HashMap<String, String> storedata;
public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);          

    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_row, null);

        TextView store = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.storeText); // title
        TextView store_num = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.store_num); // artist name
        TextView street = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.address);
        TextView city = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.city);
        Button newbutton=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.newser);
        Button historybutton=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.history);
        storedata = new HashMap<String, String>();
        storedata = data.get(position);
        newbutton.setTag(position);
         newbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent chart = new Intent();         
                  chart.setClass(v.getContext(), SectionActivity.class); 
                 storedata = data.get((Integer)v.getTag());
                  sn = storedata.get("Store_Num");
                  String store = storedata.get("Store");
                  chart.putExtra("sn", sn);
                  chart.putExtra("store", store);
                  chart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                  v.getContext().startActivity(chart); 
            }
        });

         historybutton.setTag(position);
         historybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Intent chart = new Intent();         
                      chart.setClass(v.getContext(), HistoryList.class); 
                     storedata = data.get((Integer)v.getTag());
                      sn = storedata.get("Store_Num");
                      String store = storedata.get("Store");
                      chart.putExtra("sn", sn);
                      chart.putExtra("store", store);
                      chart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                      v.getContext().startActivity(chart); 
                }
            });



        // Setting all values in listview
        store.setText(storedata.get("Store"));
        store_num.setText(storedata.get("Store_Num"));
        street.setText(storedata.get("Address"));
        city.setText(storedata.get("City") + " " + storedata.get("State") + " " + storedata.get("Zip"));

        return vi;
}
public boolean onLoadClass(Class arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

//Added for search BJR 5-16-2013
public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
    return null;
}

}
```

LOGCAT

```
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at com.tpssquared.ole.StoresActivity$1.onTextChanged(StoresActivity.java:89)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7875)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7922)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:8285)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:892)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:266)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:443)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:420)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:29)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:725)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:201)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:154)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4722)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
05-16 15:37:04.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26232):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the stack trace so we can see what line is crashing.  It would be nice if you could comment it as well.

Comment: just posted my logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Added for search BJR 5-16-2013
public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
    return null;
}
```

Yet you call `getFilter.filter()`.  I think you forgot to implement something