# How to use filter in ListView?

Tags: java, android, filter

I have ListView of names and I have EditText-"inputSearch".
I tried to use the getFilter method in order to show the names that contain the inserted text in "inputSearch" , but I got only the names that start with the input text instead of containing it.

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
   inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

   inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        } 

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }


        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

        }

    });
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14359161/768655)

Comment: You need to show us your filter class