# Search in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to add a search the `ListView` capability following [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/) tutorial. The problem is that I am not able to show anything when I type something in the search `EditText`. I want to be able to display what the user is searching but that is not what's happening. What changes do I need to make to the following code so this can be achieved?

**Code:**

```
private void loadList()
{
    Cursor res = tbl_business_desc.getRegisterData();
    int count = res.getCount();
    lvListItemsData = new android.projects.helper.mylist.ListViewItems[count];
    res.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        String ControlNum  = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(tbl_business_desc.col_ControlNum));
        String BizName     = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(tbl_business_desc.col_BizName));
        String Owner       = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(tbl_business_desc.col_Owner));
        String Add         = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(tbl_business_desc.col_Add));
        String Tel         = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(tbl_business_desc.col_Tel));
        String Email       = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(tbl_business_desc.col_Email));
        lvListItemsData[i] = new android.projects.helper.mylist.ListViewItems(ControlNum,BizName,Owner,Add,Tel,Email);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    lvList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMylist);
    inputSearch  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Set the adapter to our ListView
    lvListadapter = new android.projects.helper.list.ListViewItemsAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row_masterlist_body, lvListItemsData);
    lvList.setAdapter(lvListadapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MyListActivity.this.lvListadapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    lvList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            showStatus(position);
        }
    });
}
```

ListViewItemAdapter Code

```
public class ListViewItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItems> {

    Context mContext;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ListViewItems data[] = null;

    public ListViewItemsAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ListViewItems[] data) {

        super(mContext, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItem = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        listItem = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        // get the elements in the layout
        TextView textControlNum   = (TextView) listItem
                .findViewById(R.id.txtControlNum);

        TextView textBizName = (TextView) listItem
                .findViewById(R.id.txtBizName);

        TextView textOwner = (TextView) listItem
                .findViewById(R.id.txtOwner);

        TextView textAdd = (TextView) listItem
                .findViewById(R.id.txtAdd);

        TextView textTel = (TextView) listItem
                .findViewById(R.id.txtTel);

        TextView textEmail = (TextView) listItem
                .findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);


        ListViewItems listViewItems = data[position];

        try {
            textControlNum.setText(listViewItems.ControlNum);
            textBizName.setText(listViewItems.BizName);
            textOwner.setText(listViewItems.Owner);
            textAdd.setText(listViewItems.Add);
            textTel.setText(listViewItems.Tel);
            textEmail.setText(listViewItems.Email);

        }
        catch (Exception e){}

        if(position % 2 == 0){
            listItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(243,251,254));
        }else{
            listItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
        }   
        return listItem;
    }


}
```

Comment: write listener code in onCreate method of activity

Comment: Still the same issue, no result when typing in the search text.

Comment: Could you show `ListViewItemsAdapter`?

Comment: Added @KeLiuyue. Thanks

Comment: You can  `implements Filterable` . And look [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result/8678198#8678198](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result/8678198#8678198)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to overrride filter in your adapter class. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456525/how-to-filter-listview-using-getfilter-in-baseadapter) SO answer. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a break point at line

```
 MyListActivity.this.lvListadapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
```

to see whether the event has been triggered by text change.

Second, as you could see in source code of ArrayFilter, it filters the item by code

```
if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                        newValues.add(value);
                    } else {
                        final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
                        for (String word : words) {
                            if (word.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                                newValues.add(value);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Therefore, if there is nothing left, it might be that, it should be nothing left.