# Parsing a JSON and extracting items with condition

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

My question is similar to this [Implementing Search Filter in Adapter Class which parses a json array (without using pojo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134956/implementing-search-filter-in-adapter-class-which-parses-a-json-array-without-u/57164465?noredirect=1#comment100863370_57164465)
but I would like to try to struggle the problem differently. I have a list of elements that must be filtered based on a condition and once this condition is verified, I want to retrieve the elements that verify it from the json array. In this example, I filtered the elements based on their name, and in the setContentValue () I would set the code and the hex string taking only those elements that have that name, otherwise during filtering the name has a different index from the code and the hex strings. How could I do that?

*Fragment*

```
public class ColorViewFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private JSONArray json;
private ColorListAdapter adapter;

private EditText editColor;

@Nullable @Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_list, container, false);
    this.recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    /*
    try {
        this.recyclerView.setAdapter(new ColorListAdapter(this.json));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    */

    try {
        adapter = new ColorListAdapter(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    this.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //
    editColor = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editColor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            ColorViewFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void setJSON(JSONArray newJson){
    this.json = newJson;
}
```

*Adapter*

```
public class ColorListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements Filterable {

private JSONArray colorList;

private List<String> colorListFiltered = new ArrayList<String>();

public ColorListAdapter(JSONArray json) throws JSONException {
    super();
    if (json != null) {
        this.colorList = json;

            for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                //colorListFiltered.add((colorList.getString(i)));
                colorListFiltered.add(json.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
            }
    }
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new colorFilter();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_color_view, viewGroup, false);
    return new ColorListHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    try {
        ((ColorListHolder) viewHolder).setContentValue(i);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.colorListFiltered.size();
}

private class ColorListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView colorCodeText;
    private TextView colorNameText;
    private CardView imageView;

    public ColorListHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.colorCodeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorCode_text);
        this.colorNameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorName_text);
        this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorView);
    }

    public void setContentValue(int index) throws JSONException {

        this.colorNameText.setText(colorListFiltered.get(index));
        //this.colorNameText.setText(((JSONObject) colorList.get(index)).getString("Name"));
        this.colorCodeText.setText(((JSONObject) colorList.get(index)).getString("ColorCode"));
        this.imageView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(((JSONObject) colorList.get(index)).getString("HexString")));

    }
}


public class colorFilter extends Filter{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults Result = new FilterResults();
        // if constraint is empty return the original names

        if(constraint.length() == 0 ) {
            ArrayList<String> arrColorList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < colorList.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    arrColorList.add(colorList.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Result.values = arrColorList;
            Result.count = arrColorList.size();
            return Result;
        }

        /*if(constraint.length() == 0 ){
            Result.values = colorList;
            Result.count = colorList.length();
            return Result;*/

        else {

            List<String> Filtered_Names = new ArrayList<String>();
            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            String filterableString = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < colorList.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    filterableString = (colorList.getJSONObject(i)).getString("Name");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    Filtered_Names.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            Result.values = Filtered_Names;
            Result.count = Filtered_Names.size();
            return Result;

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        colorListFiltered = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem is here? Does not filter work? Or it does but works wrong?

Comment: Thank you for answer. So...the list is filtered by name, but, when I type a name, it seems that the names are filtered, but each name has wrong code and wrong hex string (coloring a card using parsecolor) in the view. I think because in the setContentValue() I need to extract that values where names are equal to that I filtered. But I don't know how..I have also tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134956/implementing-search-filter-in-adapter-class-which-parses-a-json-array-without-u/57164465?noredirect=1#comment100863370_57164465 But doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You use `colorListFiltered` for names but you use `colorList` for hex codes in `setContentValue`. First two lists are same but when you filter `colorListFiltered` they are getting different.

Change this,

```
 private JSONArray colorList;

 private List<String> colorListFiltered = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to

```
private List<JSONObject> colorList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

private List<JSONObject> colorListFiltered = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
```

and your `performFiltering`

```
List<JSONObject> Filtered_Names = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
                String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                String filterableString = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < colorList.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        filterableString = (colorList.get(i)).getString("Name");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                        Filtered_Names.add(colorList.get(i));
                    }
                }
```

`setContentValue`:

public void setContentValue(int index) throws JSONException {

```
this.colorNameText.setText(colorListFiltered.get(index).getString("Name"));
this.colorCodeText.setText(colorListFiltered.get(index).getString("ColorCode"));
this.imageView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorListFiltered.get(index).getString("HexString"));
```

}

Comment: Thanks for help. So...I think colorList.getJSONObject(i) should be colorList.get(i) and colorListFiltered = (ArrayList<JSONObject>) results.values in publishResults; Now I need to change colorList and colorListfiltered initialization in constructort..how?

Comment: I answered without trying so it can has some bugs you need to fix. Lets try :)

Comment: I am near solution, list loads and get filtered, but when I delete word, I get a ClassCastException: String cannot be cast to JSONObject (in setContentValue). Maybe because when I delete word, It is seen as an object by the setText...how to fix that? thank you.

Comment: Which line `this.colorNameText.setText` or `this.colorCodeText.setText`?

Comment: this.colorNameText.setText and "Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.List<org.json.JSONObject>" in colorListFiltered = (List<JSONObject>) results.values;

Comment: It seems fixed with if(constraint.equals(null)) instead of if(constraint.lenght() == 0) in performFiltering(). Let me do more tests...

Answer (score 0):

I am near solution, list loads and get filtered, but when I delete word, I get a ClassCastException: String cannot be cast to JSONObject (in setContentValue).

```
public class ColorListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements Filterable {

        private List<JSONObject> colorList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        private List<JSONObject> colorListFiltered = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        public ColorListAdapter(JSONArray json) throws JSONException {

            super();
            if (json != null) {


                for(int i=0; i<json.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    colorList.add(jsonObj);

                    colorListFiltered = colorList;

                }

            }
        }


        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new colorFilter();
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_color_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new ColorListHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            try {
                ((ColorListHolder) viewHolder).setContentValue(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return this.colorListFiltered.size();

        }

        private class ColorListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private TextView colorNameText;
            private TextView colorCodeText;
            private CardView imageView;

            public ColorListHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                this.colorCodeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorCode_text);
                this.colorNameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorName_text);
                this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorView);
            }


            public void setContentValue(final int index) throws JSONException {


                this.colorNameText.setText(colorListFiltered.get(index).getString("Name"));
                this.colorCodeText.setText(colorListFiltered.get(index).getString("ColorCode"));
                this.imageView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorListFiltered.get(index).getString("HexString")));

                }
        }


        //filtro su Name
        public class colorFilter extends Filter{

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults Result = new FilterResults();

                // if constraint is empty return the original names
                if(constraint.length() == 0 ) {
                    ArrayList<String> arrNameList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < colorList.size(); i++) {
                        try {
                            arrNameList.add(colorList.get(i).getString("Name"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    Result.values = arrNameList;
                    Result.count = arrNameList.size();
                    return Result;
                }

                else {

                    List<JSONObject> Filtered_Names = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
                    String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    String filterableString = "";

                    for (int i = 0; i < colorList.size(); i++) {
                        try {
                            filterableString = (colorList.get(i)).getString("Name");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                            Filtered_Names.add(colorList.get(i));
                        }
                    }

                    Result.values = Filtered_Names;
                    Result.count = Filtered_Names.size();
                    return Result;

                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                colorListFiltered = (ArrayList<JSONObject>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }
```